# HTML Parsing using file_get_html not working

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```
<?php
 require_once('simple_html_dom.php'); 
 $fileName = '/Users/.../Documents/.../.../abcdef.html';
 echo file_get_html($fileName)->plaintext;
?>
```

When I run the php file with above code I don't get any content. It is just blank.
I have simple_html_dom.php and file on right paths.
Nothing in logs too. May I know what I am missing?

Comment: what does "echo file_get_contents($fileName);" return?

Comment: Nothing. Web Page is Empty.

Comment: So that file is empty? Are those `...`s literally `...`s?

Comment: No. It is not an empty file. 
....s I just did it for simplicity. But in my actual code there is a valid path.